# IP of a Outgoing Request from AWS EC2 behind ELB

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I have a single EC2 with a EIP behind a ELB.
All the incoming requests are hiting the ELB and reaching EC2 webserver, as expected.
Now from my PHP application I do a Outgoing Curl request to another server (not in AWS) and check the request IP there, it is showing the ELB IP from Pool.
I was expecting it to show the EIP of the EC2.

Is there something that I am missing, do I need any specific header in Curl request to see EIP in another server?

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=125346 this thread someone mentioned following, and i was expecting same.

> When you receive incoming traffic through the load balancer, the
>   responses will go out the same way. However, traffic that is
>   originating from your instance will not pass through the load
>   balancer. Instead, it is sent directly from the public IP address of
>   your instance out to the Internet. The ELB is not involved in that
>   scenario

Comment: The quote is correct. It should not be using the ELB IP address. Please edit your question to show the evidence you have, and the steps you took, that make you think this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for asking me the evidence, I was able to reproduce this again and again in my applications, but to give you evidence I wrote simple php scripts and figured it that as my "another server" was also behind a ELB, and the ELB IP that I was seeing on the application was not ELB IP of my EC2 but ELB ip of "another server".

Comment: BTW both my application are in Laravel framework. and the "another server application is not picking the IP from "X-Forwarded" header by default.